# Get a list of maximum values per tuple from a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples, max

I'm just getting into Python, and having some trouble understanding the control flow and iteration logic.

I am trying to create a function which takes a list of tuples, and I want to return a new list with the maximum element per tuple.

I know I'm missing putting the maximum element into a new list, but first I am trying to get that maximum value.

```
def max_element_per_tuple(tuple_list):
    maximum = tuple_list[0]

    for item in tuple_list:
        if item > maximum:
            maximum = item

    return maximum

# test it
tuple_list = [(-1,0,1), (10,20,30), (100,50,25), (55,75,65)]
print(max_element_per_tuple(tuple_list))
```

This returns: `(100, 50, 25)`

Want returned: `(1, 30, 100, 75)`

Or if a list (?), then: `[1, 30, 100, 75]`

Comment: Can't you just use `max()`?

Comment: You're missing one loop level. Your input is a list of tuples. So `for item in tuple_list` is looping through the tuples. Now you will want to loop `for element in item` to loop each number inside each tuple. BUT, why not use [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max)?

Comment: I'm still learning the basics of looping, so the intent was to solve with loops. I see the helpfulness of the max() function though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you are just looping through the tuples and returning the "biggest" one - tuple comparison is done element-wise.

What you want is to add another loop level that will find the maximum of **each** tuple:

```py
def max_element_per_tuple(tuple_list):
    res = []

    for tup in tuple_list:      # loops over the tuples in the list
        maximum = tup[0]
        for item in tup:        # loops over each item of the tuple
            if item > maximum:
                maximum = item
        res.append(maximum)

    return res
```

This gives as expected:

```
>>> max_element_per_tuple([(-1, 0, 1), (10, 20, 30), (100, 50, 25), (55, 75, 65)])
[1, 30, 100, 75]
```

Comment: Based on using loops for the sake of the exercise and not the `max()' function, this is correct in what I was trying to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Simply, try this one-linear pythonic solution

```
>>> tuple_list = [(-1,0,1), (10,20,30), (100,50,25), (55,75,65)]
>>> [max(e) for e in tuple_list]       # List
[1, 30, 100, 75]
>>> tuple(max(e) for e in tuple_list)  # Tuple
(1, 30, 100, 75)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function `max_element_per_tuple` is correct (though unnecessary, because standard function `max()` exists). What you did wrong was calling that function using a list of tuples as the argument. This found the biggest tuple in the list ("biggest" for tuples means "the one with first element biggest"), which happened to be the third one - `(100,50,25)`. What you need to do is either:

```
result = list(map(max, tuple_list))
```

or

```
result = [max(t) for t in tuple_list]
```

This last one is roughly equivalent to:

```
result = []
for t in tuple_list:
    result.append(max(t))
```

If you replace `max` with your `max_element_per_tuple` the results should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
def max_element_per_tuple(tuple_list):
    maximum = []

    for item in tuple_list:
        maximum.append(max(item))


    return maximum
```

will give this output : `[1, 30, 100, 75]`

Answer (score 1):

The issue: max_element_per_tuple(tuple_list) returns the wrong result because it is looking for the max tuple, not the max value in each tuple.

```
def max_element_per_tuple(tuple_list):
    maximum = tuple_list[0]  # maximum is = (-1,0,1)

    for item in tuple_list:
        if item > maximum:  # compares the tuples e.g (-1,0,1) == (10,20,30)
            maximum = item

    return maximum  # at the end you have (100,50,25). it's the max tuple
```

Try any of below options:

```
tuple_list = [(-1,0,1), (10,20,30), (100,50,25), (55,75,65)]

# Get the max from each tuple using List comprehension
max_items_list  = [max(tuple_item) for tuple_item in tuple_list]   # in a list
max_items_tuple = tuple(max(tuple_item) for tuple_item in tuple_list)   # in a tuple
print(max_items_list)
print(max_items_tuple)

# Get the max from each tuple using For Loop
# Can be used with List only, tuples are immutable

for_max_items_list = list()

for tuple_item in tuple_list:
  max_value = max(tuple_item)  # get the max of each tuple e.g Max((-1,0,1)) = 1
  for_max_items_list.append(max_value)  # add the max to list
print(for_max_items_list)
```